# saving mcmc result for later in pymc3

Tags: pickle, pymc3

This question is related to the wonderful `pymc3` module.  I want to save an mcmc result to disk so that later, when new data comes in, I can use `sample_ppc` without having to train again.  Here is some code that does exactly that, borrowed from [PyMC3's documentation on posterior checks](http://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/posterior_predictive.html?highlight=sample_ppc):

```
from theano import shared
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm

def learn():
    def invlogit(x):        
      return np.exp(x) / (1 + np.exp(x))

    coeff = 1
    predictors = np.random.normal(size=1e6)

    predictors_shared = shared(predictors)
    outcomes = np.random.binomial(1, invlogit(coeff * predictors))

    def tinvlogit(x):
        import theano.tensor as t
        return t.exp(x) / (1 + t.exp(x))

    with pm.Model() as model:
        coeff = pm.Normal('coeff', mu=0, sd=1)
        p = tinvlogit(coeff * predictors_shared)
        o = pm.Bernoulli('o', p, observed=outcomes)
        trace = pm.sample(5000, n_init=5000)

    # reduce the shared variable memory requirement
    predictors_shared.set_value(np.zeros(1))

    return {'trace': trace, 'model': model, 'predictors_shared': predictors_shared}

def predict(trace, model, predictors_shared):
    predictors_oos = np.random.normal(size=50)
    predictors_shared.set_value(predictors_oos)
    return pm.sample_ppc(trace, model=model, samples=500)
```

First we learn:

```
import pickle
learned_result = learn()
with open('some/file.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(learned_result, f)
```

Then we unpickle and make predictions for new data:

```
with open('some/file.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    learned_result = pickle.load(learned_result, f)
ppc = predict(**learned_result)
```

And this works great except for a storage problem -- the pickled `learned_result` is huge. The killer is `model`.  Judging by the relative sizes, I think the `model` is storing internally the entire training dataset.  Is there a way to delete the internally stored data from the `model` object?  Will my `sample_ppc` still work if I do this?  Is there some theoretical reason why `model` has to keep in memory the entire training dataset in order to do a posterior predictive check?  Thank in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

save the trace, not the model, then you can build the same model and use the result without having to run the sampler again.

Comment: in that case, can you give me a snippet of code that would show how `pm.sample_ppc` could be made aware of the preserved `trace`?